# How to add more than 10 gridlines to chart

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to add more than 10 gridlines on a scatter plot chart in google sheets? I have more than 9 items on my horizontal axis and I would like a gridline for each item. Minor gridlines only put lines between the major lines.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out limiting the horizontal axis to 10 was limiting how many actual gridlines were placed. I increased the horizontal axis value and the gridlines filled in as needed.